# Admob integration without app source code

Tags: admob

Hi a developer designed my app and submitted to playstore on my behalf. I have put the app on admob as well as firebase. Is it possible to add ads without the app source code? The company is refusing to send me the source code even though I'm paying $200 per month.

Answer (score 0):

> After you've set up an app in AdMob and added an ad unit to it, the
> last step is to implement the ad unit in your app’s code.
>
> https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356427?hl=en

If the app isn't programmed to show ads, it obviously won't show any. You have to add the relevant code and upload a new version of the app to Playstore for ads to be included in the app.